# AWS ruby gem as if is not installed

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, rubygems, amazon-dynamodb

When I try to run a really small program that was nly suposed to test if I can connect to the amazon dynamoDB I get an error as if I havent installed the aws gem...

My code is the following:

```
require "AWS"

AWS.config(  access_key_id: ENV["coco"],
secret_access_key: ENV["xixi"]
)

DB = AWS::DynamoDB.new
```

And I have the following error:

```
 reducer.rb:4:in `<main>': uninitialized constant AWS (NameError)
```

The gem is installed as you can see here:

```
Bernardos-MacBook-Pro:cn bersimoes$ gem which aws
/Users/bersimoes/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/aws-2.6.0/lib/aws.rb
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’ve got the wrong gem. You want [`aws-sdk`](https://rubygems.org/gems/aws-sdk) for [`AWS::DynamoDB` support](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/1.7.1/lib/aws/dynamo_db.rb#L111). Install with:

```
gem install aws-sdk
```

You might need to uninstall the existing `aws` gem to ensure you load the right one (they both have an `aws.rb` file). Alternatively you could use `gem 'aws-sdk'` in your code before your `require` to ensure the correct gem is loaded. Another possibility is to `require 'aws-sdk'` since the gem [provides that file basically as an alias](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/1.7.1/lib/aws-sdk.rb).

Also you should use:

```
require 'aws' # note lower case
```

This probably won’t cause problems on a Mac, but will cause issues if you ever move your code to a case-sensitive machine like Linux.

Answer (score 2):

If you are receiving this error and you have the "aws-sdk" gem installed, you likely have **upgraded to version 2 of the aws-sdk gem unintentionally**. Version 2 uses the `Aws` namespace, not `AWS`. This allows version 1 and version 2 to be used in the same application.

See this [blog post](http://ruby.awsblog.com/post/TxFKSK2QJE6RPZ/Upcoming-Stable-Release-of-AWS-SDK-for-Ruby-Version-2) for more information.

Comment: The blog post in this answer led me to use `gem install aws-sdk:'< 2.0'`. This worked in my situation!

Answer (score 2):

Yeah i just ran into this issue and resolved. It is because AWS updated their gem to 2.0. If you update the gem to 2.0 different configuration is required according to this article they posted.

If you want to using the version you had before, just change the Gemfile like below:

Gemfile

gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'